# what does setting the current thread's culture code do?

Tags: asp.net, localization, culture

what is the result of setting the current thread's culture code?

I understand if I use the resource file it will pull label's/strings from the .resx file.

What else?  Will it effect my date/money formatting also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting [`Thread.CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx) will affect formatting and parsing of dates and numbers. Setting [`Thread.CurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.currentuiculture.aspx) affects fetching resources from resource files.

Answer (score 1):

yes, your Date, money and other setting will be according to your thread 's culture.
When you set thread's culture, your application run under that culture.

Answer (score 1):

It MIGHT affect date and money formatting, depending on how you do the formatting.  I think the default ToString() will usually check the treads UI culture, but if you have any custom formatting it will override the defaults.

Answer (score 1):

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb896001 National Language Support codes in various operative systems